# Need worked solution: Finding the integral of function

Tags: integration

I am new to calculus and a little intimidated by big functions. I need to understand how to integrate the following expression:

$$
\int{Q(Z)\log{P(Z)}}dz
$$

where $Q(Z) \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2) $ and $P(Z) \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, I)$. The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) where I saw the answer (at the bottom of p.10) just jumps to the result but omits the intermediate steps.

The answer I should be getting is 
$$-\frac{J}{2}\log{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{J}{(\mu_j^2+\sigma_j^2)}$$
Where $J$ is the dimension of $Z$

Please help.

Comment: what is $X$ in your case?

Comment: @Zaccarie Ramzi Sorry, instead of $X$ I should've written $Z$

Answer (score 1):

I think I now have the full step-by-step solution:

$$\int Q(X)\log P(X)dX$$

First, let's take the log apart:
$$ \log P(X) = \log \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\bigg] $$

Since $P(X) \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, I) $ is a normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$, we can write:

$$ \log P(X) = \log \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\bigg] = 
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{x^2}{2}||x||^2
$$

So the integral above becomes:
$$\int Q(X) \bigg[ -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{x^2}{2}||x||^2 \bigg]dX$$

Expanding the brackets:
$$-\frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi \int Q(X) dX - \frac{1}{2}\int Q(X) ||x||^2 dX
$$

Since by definition (see Wikipedia) $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = E[X^2] - \mu^2$ and $\int Q(X) ||x||^2 dX$ is the expectation of  $||X||^2$, i.e. $\int Q(X) ||x||^2 = E[X^2] = Var(X) + E[X]^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 $, we can write:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} E[X^2] = -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} E[\mu^2+\sigma^2]
$$

Since $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are vectors, we need to replace the expectation with a sum:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} E[X^2] = -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{J}[\mu_j^2+\sigma_j^2]
$$